# Azure Service Fabric: How to enumerate all services in an application from the Name Service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a simple stateless service that needs to make a remoting call to each of the other services within the same application. Rather than hard code a list of all the other services in the application I would prefer to get an enumeration of all services from the Name Service (or anywhere else it can be discovered). Then my code would be generic and continue to work without change when I add new services to the application in the future.

But I cannot find any documentation, or examples, that shows this enumeration capability. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `FabricClient.QueryClient` class and its `GetServiceListAsync` method:

```
using(var fabricClient = new FabricClient())
{
    var serviceList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(appUri);
    // ...
}
```

And here's relevant [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.queryclient.getservicelistasync?view=azure-dotnet)